# why is my php/mysql 'WHILE' not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have something very strange, my code basically works fine if I do this:

```
include_once ('includes/MailChimp.php');
use \Drewm;

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db_username","db_password");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db_database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, user_id, email FROM db_users");

while ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{


        echo $user['username'];
        echo '<br>';


}

mysql_close($con);
```

It prints all the usernames. No errors. But then I remove the 2 echo lines and replace them with this:

```
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
                'id'                => 'x',
                'email'             => array('email'=>$user['email']),
                'merge_vars'        => array('USERNAME'=>$user['username'], 'UID'=>$user['user_id']),
                'double_optin'      => false,
                'update_existing'   => true,
                'replace_interests' => false,
                'send_welcome'      => false,
));
```

And it suddenly doesn't work anymore, giving me this error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given
```

And it tells me the line of the error is:

```
while ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

It makes no sense if it's working fine with echo!

Comment: You've overwritten `$result` in the loop. Use a different variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the variable **$result**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, user_id, email FROM db_users");
```

and

```
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array...
```

change **$result** var for other and it works

Comment: Doh! Thank you so much!

Comment: If it works, please, value the answer